# How to output each stock?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I have to do this program where I have to display the calculation of the profit for each individual stock, but I also have to display the profit for the total amount of stocks. My code only has it so it displays the calculation for all of the stocks:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KNW_MultipleStockSales
{

  //This method will perform the calculations
  public static double calculator(double numberShare, double purchasePrice, 
                                  double purchaseCommission, double salePrice,
                                  double salesCommission)
  {
    double profit = (((numberShare * salePrice)-salesCommission) - 
                     ((numberShare * purchasePrice) + purchaseCommission));
    return profit;
  }

  //This is where we ask the questions
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Declare variables
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int stock;
    double numberShare;
    double purchasePrice;
    double purchaseCommission;
    double salePrice;
    double saleCommission;
    double profit;
    double total = 0;

    //Ask the questions
    System.out.println("Enter the stocks you have: ");
    stock = scanner.nextInt();

    //For loop for the number stock they are in
    for(int numberStocks=1; numberStocks<=stock; numberStocks++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the number of shares for stock " + numberStocks + ": ");
      numberShare = scanner.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter the purchase price" + numberStocks + ": ");
      purchasePrice = scanner.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter the purchase commissioned:" + numberStocks + ": ");
      purchaseCommission = scanner.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter the sale price:" + numberStocks + ": ");
      salePrice = scanner.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter the sales commissioned:" + numberStocks + ": ");
      saleCommission = scanner.nextDouble();

      profit = calculator(numberShare, purchasePrice, purchaseCommission,
                          salePrice, saleCommission);
      total = total + profit;
    }


      //Return if the user made profit or loss
      if(total<0)
      {
        System.out.printf("You made a loss of:$%.2f", total);
      }
      else if(total>0)
      {
        System.out.printf("You made a profit of:$%.2f", total);
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("You made no profit or loss.");
      }
  }
}
```

How can I get it so each individual stock profit gets shown, with the profit of all the stocks together?

Answer (score 0):

Try maintaining a separate Map for profit/loss. You may want to accept Stock Name as an input which will help manage individual stocks effectively.

```
 // Map of stock name and profit/loss
 Map<String,Double> profitMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();
```

After calculating profit/loss, add entry to map

```
profitMap.put("stockName", profit);
total = total + profit;
```

At the end of your program, iterate and display profit/loss for each Stock from Map.

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : profitMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Stock Name : " + entry.getKey() + " Profit/loss" + entry.getValue());
    }
```